# webpack cannot resolve non relative path generated by tsc

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have the following tsconfig.json for a package that is consumed by other packages, let us call it `packageA`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "checkJs": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./tests",
    "./dist",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

`packageA` has non-relative paths, e.g.

`import { T } from 'src/components/Translations';`

`tsc` transpiles this to:

`var Translations_1 = require("src/components/Translations")`.

## The problem occurs when I am compiling a different package (`packageB`) using webpack that consumes `packageA`

I have `main` in `packageA`'s `package.json` like this:

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts"
```

And `index.ts` has exports like this:

`export * from 'src/selectors/ui';`

which transpiles to this

`__exportStar(require('src/selectors/ui'), exports);`

When I am compiling `packageB` that has consumes `packageA` as a dependency.

`import { selector } from 'packageA`;

This will load `node_modules/packageA/dist/index.js`

ts-loader emits the following error

`Cannot find module: 'src/selectors/ui'.

The problem is that the transpiled code from `packageA` looks like this.

`__exportStar(require('src/selectors/ui'), exports);`

But the `dist` folder looks like this:

```
|
ui
|
translations
```

`src` does not exist in the `dist` directory specified with the `outDir` in `tsconfig.json`

I tried adding an alias in webpack like this:

```
alias: {
  'webpack/hot/poll': require.resolve('webpack/hot/poll'),
  src: 'dist',
},
```

This actually does fix it for `packageA` but then this breaks `packageB`'s resolution that also has non-relative imports like:

`import { App } from 'src/containers'`

The problem is that `src` is mapped to `dist` for every import as I can see in the webpack output

`aliased with mapping 'src': 'dist' to 'dist/containers/App'`

And of course, I get the error

> Cannot find module: 'src/containers/App'

Can I map `src` to `dist` only for specific modules and not everything?

Everything works if `packageA` has relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem once, and my solution to non-relative paths issue is to use the paths property like shown below. This will change your require path when importing the component from `import { T } from 'src/components/Translations';` to `import { T } from 'components/Translations';` which I prefer but can be tweaked. Check out the TypeScript handbook for more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
               "*": ["src/*", "node_modules/*"]
        },
        "checkJs": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5"
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "./tests",
        "./dist",
        "src/**/*.test.ts",
        "src/**/*.test.tsx",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
      ]
    }
```

Comment: I have updated the question with some more context.  The error actually occurs in packages that consume this package.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I suggest to change `packageA` which you treat as library to build with https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttypescript where you can use a plugin to transform non-relative -> relative path as we build thing. Here is the helpful plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-transform-paths. Then your `tsconfig` file would look like:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "paths": {
    "src/*": ["./src/*"]
  },
  "declaration": true,
  "plugins": [
    { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },
    { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
  ]
},
```

In your package script build, you have to change `tsc` -> `ttsc` as well:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "ttsc"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute paths can be resolved by adding `src` to the resolved modules in `webpack.config.js`.

A high level overview of how webpack module resolution works can be found [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/).

Config details can be found [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules).

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
  },
};
reso
```